# Where is system.log in TimeMachine backup

Tags: macos, time-machine, logs

I would like to get older versions of /private/var/log/system.log files from TimeMachine.  Is this possible?  How?

I see current system.log files. I went to folder /private/var/log then invoked TimeMachine.

[image]

When I go back to previous backup, I do not see system.log files.

[image]

relates to 
[can-i-find-out-the-last-time-a-specific-usb-was-connected-to-my-mbp7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366132/can-i-find-out-the-last-time-a-specific-usb-was-connected-to-my-mbp/366157?noredirect=1#comment490489_366157)

User want to look through macOS log files to see history of external drive mounting. Data is in "/private/var/log/system.log".  Needed data is a month old. A month is longer than normal backup of system.log is keep.  Attempted to look in timemachine backup but it seems the older system.log files are not kept.

Comment: System log files are excluded from TM backups (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-os-x-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup) and the file /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist). AIUI this is because log files change all the time, and the method TM uses to make incremental backups would not work well with log files.

Comment: TimeMachine is intended as a safetynet for users, as such, it doesn’t track temporal system data. This is common accross many backup and versioning solutions

Answer (score 3):

Everything in /private is excluded by rule - including /var/log/system.log

```
tmutil isexcluded /private/var/log/*
```

More details on this are at [On OS X, what files are excluded by rule from a Time Machine backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-os-x-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup)

You would need another tool to back these up as I’ve not had luck using the `tmutil removeexclusion /var/log/system.log` command which might have worked if the exclusion was based on a file pattern and not the rule.